# Simple numpy broadcasting

Tags: numpy, array-broadcasting

I'm sure this question has an answer already somewhere, but I'm having trouble finding it since there are so many broadcasting questions, so perhaps someone can either point to it or answer directly.

I want to apply a function to each element of a NumPy array.

I have:

```
def test1(x):
    return np.sum(x)
def test2(y):
    return test1([5.0, y])
test2([1.0,2.0,3.0])
# I want the result to be [6.0, 7.0, 8.0]
# But I get TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'float' and 'list'
```

How can I do this?

In Julia it would be:

```
test2.([1.0,2.0,3.0])
```

Thanks

Comment: you could do `test1(np.concatenate([y, [5.0]]))`.

Comment: You give `test2` a `list`.  Look at what it gives to `test1` `[5,[1,2,3]]`

Comment: @hpaulj I understand why what I wrote doesn't work. But in Julia, you could use the . syntax to make it work as indicated. I'm wondering if there is an equivalent in numpy?

Comment: The problem isn't with the calling syntax.  You just need to be careful when mixing lists, numbers, and arrays.  `np.sum` says its first argument is supposed to be `array_like`.  `[5, [1,2,3]]` is not a good array input.

Comment: AFAIK, the `dot` operator is the `julia` syntax for vectorized function calls (not *broadcasted*). With `numpy` that would translate to `np.vectorize(test2)([1.0,2.0,3.0])`. Since `numpy` will not be compiled or jitted, this kind of function call vectorization is slow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the full error message - which for some reason you decided wasn't relevant!

```
In [99]: def test1(x):
    ...:     return np.sum(x)
    ...: def test2(y):
    ...:     return test1([5.0, y])
    ...: test2([1.0,2.0,3.0])
/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/numpy/core/fromnumeric.py:86: VisibleDeprecationWarning: Creating an ndarray from ragged nested sequences (which is a list-or-tuple of lists-or-tuples-or ndarrays with different lengths or shapes) is deprecated. If you meant to do this, you must specify 'dtype=object' when creating the ndarray.
  return ufunc.reduce(obj, axis, dtype, out, **passkwargs)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  Input In [99] in <cell line: 5>
    test2([1.0,2.0,3.0])
  Input In [99] in test2
    return test1([5.0, y])
  Input In [99] in test1
    return np.sum(x)
  File <__array_function__ internals>:180 in sum
  File /usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/numpy/core/fromnumeric.py:2298 in sum
    return _wrapreduction(a, np.add, 'sum', axis, dtype, out, keepdims=keepdims,
  File /usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/numpy/core/fromnumeric.py:86 in _wrapreduction
    return ufunc.reduce(obj, axis, dtype, out, **passkwargs)
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'float' and 'list'
```

Let's add a debugging print to `test1`:

```
In [100]: def test1(x):
     ...:     print(x)
     ...:     return np.sum(x)
     ...: test2([1.0,2.0,3.0])
[5.0, [1.0, 2.0, 3.0]]
....
```

Do you understand why `x` is this list - with a number and a list?

`np.sum` is a numpy function, and like most, it converts the input into an array first:

```
In [101]: np.array([5.0, [1.0, 2.0, 3.0]])
<ipython-input-101-79819e7b65b8>:1: VisibleDeprecationWarning: Creating an ndarray from ragged nested sequences (which is a list-or-tuple of lists-or-tuples-or ndarrays with different lengths or shapes) is deprecated. If you meant to do this, you must specify 'dtype=object' when creating the ndarray.
  np.array([5.0, [1.0, 2.0, 3.0]])
Out[101]: array([5.0, list([1.0, 2.0, 3.0])], dtype=object)
```

If we pass an array instead, we still get the ragged array warning, but it runs:

```
In [102]: test2(np.array([1,2,3]))
[5.0, array([1, 2, 3])]
/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/numpy/core/fromnumeric.py:86: VisibleDeprecationWarning: Creating an ndarray from ragged nested sequences (which is a list-or-tuple of lists-or-tuples-or ndarrays with different lengths or shapes) is deprecated. If you meant to do this, you must specify 'dtype=object' when creating the ndarray.
  return ufunc.reduce(obj, axis, dtype, out, **passkwargs)
Out[102]: array([6., 7., 8.])
```

`np.sum` can operate on the `5.0` and `np.array([1,2,3])`

If we use the python `sum` instead, the number and array do add - without that intermediate step of creating a ragged array:

```
In [104]: sum([5, np.array([1,2,3])])
Out[104]: array([6, 7, 8])
```

Or the full function sequence:

```
In [105]: def test1(x):
     ...:     return sum(x)
     ...: def test2(y):
     ...:     return test1([5.0, y])
     ...: test2(np.array([1.0,2.0,3.0]))
Out[105]: array([6., 7., 8.])
```

Another version:

```
In [111]: def test1(x):
     ...:     return np.add(*x)
     ...: def test2(y):
     ...:     return test1([5.0, y])
     ...: test2([1.0,2.0,3.0])
Out[111]: array([6., 7., 8.])
```

`np.sum` takes an array(-like), and sums all the terms.  `np.add` takes two arguments, and adds them (with `broadcasting`).  `*x` is used to unpack the `test2` list.  `np.add` will convert the list `y` to array as needed.

Stripped of the function calls, what you are trying to do is:

```
In [112]: 5 + np.array([1,2,3])
Out[112]: array([6, 7, 8])
```

Comment: Oh definitely. I was just wondering if there is an equivalent of the Julia approach: `test2.([1.0,2.0,3.0])`

Comment: So it sounds like what you get in Julia by using dot syntax is actually the default behavior in numpy as long as everything is an array.

Comment: It's the use of `np.sum` that's giving problems.  Use `np.add` instead.